# can australian schools track your personal home laptops and see your info?

Tags: tracking

I am curious if the schools can track what you do at home or see your history. I am worried about the schools having full access to my personal pc when I don't even know about that e.g., see my passwords, see my downloads Apps, delete my files, track what I do on my laptop at home and do they have remote access to my pc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my school see what I'm doing on my laptop at home?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215532/can-my-school-see-what-im-doing-on-my-laptop-at-home), [Can my school track my laptop?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235229/can-my-school-track-my-laptop)., [Can my school monitor what I do on my personal device?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241117/can-my-school-monitor-what-i-do-on-my-personal-device).